# Who has the ownership of a temporary value when it is created and referred by a struct?

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

```rust
 // code snippet 1
 1 #[derive(Debug)]
 2 struct Foo<'a> {
 3     i: &'a String,
 4 }
 5
 6 fn main(){
 7     let foo: Foo = Foo {
 8         i: &"".to_owned(),
 9     };
10     println!("{:?}", foo);
11 }
```

I feel confused about the code snippet above. What I have learned told me that every value in Rust has an owner, which is responsible for the resource deallocation, this is the mechanism called `ownership` .

This aligns great when it comes like this:

```rust
// code snippet 2
0 fn main() {
1     let str: String = String::from("hello");   
2 }
```

In `code snippet 2` ,  `str` is an owner on the stack, when it goes out of the scope in line 2, the contents on the heap("hello") are deallocated, which is quite clear.

But in `code snippet 1`, line 8, `"".to_owned()` , we create a `String` but don't explicitly bind it to any variable. Instead, we give it to the field `i` of `foo` in the form of `reference`. This is weird, `"".to_owned()`  doesn't have an owner, but we lend it to someone else.

Then, I decided to create my own `struct` instead of using `String` from standard library, simulate a similar situation in `code snippet 1` , and implement `std::ops::Drop` for it to see when is this value freed.

```rust
 // code snippet 3
 1 #![allow(unused)]
 2
 3 struct MyStruct;
 4
 5 struct Foo<'a>{
 6     i: &'a MyStruct,
 7 }
 8
 9 impl Drop for MyStruct {
10     fn drop(&mut self){
11         println!("MyStruct is dropped.");
12     }
13 }
14
15 impl<'a> Drop for Foo<'a>{
16     fn drop(&mut self){
17         println!("Foo is dropped.");
18     }
19 }
20
21 fn main(){
22     let foo: Foo = Foo{
23         i: &MyStruct,
24     };
25 }
```

Here is the running result:

```sh
# result: (t is my crate name)
➜  t cargo run -q   
Foo is dropped.
MyStruct is dropped.
```

`MyStruct` is deallocated after `Foo` 's deallocation as we can see.

So I am guessing the owner of `MyStruct` is `foo`, which is also the owner of `Foo` struct?

Or the owner of `MyStruct` is `foo.i`, but can a reference be an owner in Rust?

If you found my question irregular, feel free to point it out :)

Comment: I hope the tagged duplicate answers your question. If not, please let me know, and I'll try to fill in any missing details.